# Adding a path to DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: bash, environment-variables

In my .bash_profile I have the following lines:

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path_1"
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path_2:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

but for some reason using echo I see only path_1, and path_2 is not appended. Can you help me figuring out why?

Comment: Hi Laura, this seems ok to me. Are you sure you typed this exactly (without any other blank space around the = for example) ?

Comment: It should work as written. I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, I am sure...the funny thing is that if I type these commands in the shell it works, but if I type them in .bash_profile it does not!

Comment: I am working in MacOS Sierra 10.12.6 (in case this can be of any significance...)

Comment: Perhaps you're misunderstanding the conditions under which *~/.bash_profile* is read. It is only read by interactive shells and only if it's a login shell. So if it isn't read you may be seeing the value of the var as set by some other config file.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that I had two .bash_profile, but only one was the right one! Thanks all!